# Reading Spark Dataframe from S3 Bucket While Another Process Writes to it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-emr, bucket

Would there be any issues reading a spark dataframe and say persisting it via a Jupyter notebook and another process writing to the s3 bucket concurrently?

Say,

I read a dataframe like:

```
 s3 = spark.read.parquet('s3://path/to/table')
```

And work on this in a notebook.

Concurrently I write out to the same s3 bucket at some point via a different process, e.g.

```
system('s3-dist-cp --src --dest s3://path/to/table)
```

Would this ever prove to be an issue? I am ok with messing up the read / dataframe but I would not want to block writing out to the bucket.

Answer (score 2):

This will cause FNF exception on any action on the first DF that you read.

```
 s3 = spark.read.parquet('s3://path/to/table')
```

The first spark job that is involved in the above is listing leaf files and directories. As there was another process that was writing/ rewriting data, the paths would be stale.

Furthermore, the eventual consistency behavior of the S3 should also be considered.

Comment: So basically let's say hypothetically I submit a GET (spark.read.parquet) and PUT (s3-dist-cp) exactly concurrently. It would put these into a queue and perform the operations in order so there would be no conflict. However, because we have to consider the eventual consistency model we could have cases where we write out during (rather slightly before) or before our read process. We will have a previous version of the data until the cache is recreated for that bucket. I think that's the correct understanding? I'm also not understanding how the paths would be stale?

Comment: I've answered myself on the last question, looks like it would be because we aren't guaranteed the same partitions / sub-directories in the new buckets right?

Comment: S3 offers list inconsistency: listings often lag files being created/deleted, which breaks spark, and update inconsistency: if you overwrite an existing file and then try to read it, the reader may get the old data. Nothing in Spark expects that